# Nativescript/Angular. When build, all the images in App_Resources are ignored

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript

As the post title says: When build my Nativescript project, all the images in App_Resources are ignored.

And replaced by the default Nativescript icons, splashs, etc.

I'm using the latest version of all the dependencies: cli, angular, nativescript.

Some idea to fix this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try `tns run android --clean` ? It will clean the platforms so all changes made to them should be applied.

Comment: `try to remove the `platforms` folder and rebuild. Make sure you are changing the images in `app/App_resources/Android/...` and not in `plaforms/android/...`

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue moving the drawable-xxx folders from

App_Resources\Android\

to

App_Resources\Android\src\main\res\